# Sending parameters to segue from inside a custom table cell?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, segue

I have a `UITableView` with a custom table cell which has several controls on it - one of them is a button.

When clicking the cell itself I'm sending some data via a segue to a view controller - that works fine.

I want to open a different view controller when the button form inside the cell is clicked - and again, send some data.

The button is connected to the view controller which is opening fine when the button is clicked.

The problem is I can't get the `IndexPath` inside the `prepareForSegue` in order to set the parameter I wish to send to the view controller.

This code brings the first object from the table datasource:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"CommentSegue"])
 {

    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *detail = [myObject objectAtIndex:path.row];
    CommentViewController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
    navController.data=detail;
 }
}
```

While I want the n item which the button belongs to...

Thanks.

Comment: So the sender is the button in the second case?

Comment: Yes. I was able to identify the button as sender - but couldn't get the the cell from it (using super)

Comment: if you only have one section, set the tag of UIButton to the row of `UIIndexPath`, so you can derive the indexpath from sender.tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never call a segue from within the cell itself.

You have to define a target for the button in `-tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when populating the data for the cell.

do this:

`[cell.theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

and to get the index of the row that button belongs to, use this trick:
`cell.theButton.tag = indexPath.row`

you can then handle the click on your table view controller like this:

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton *) button
{
     NSInteger index = button.tag;
     // now prepare the data and perform segue
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why "You should never call a segue from within the cell itself"?